# SSL enabling in Tomcat Windows server

Tags: windows, ssl, https, tomcat7

I want to enable https on my website which is on a Windows Server 2008 and tomcat 7. 
I have the following files from a certificate website: .ca, .crt, .pem, .csr, .pkcs

I know that i have to add in tomcat's server.xml the following:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/path/to/Tomcat/keystore.jks"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

How to get that .jks from those files ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your .pem to a .jks:  see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html

Answer (score 0):

If your using tomcat 7 newest version you can install the certificate to the windows secure keystore (cert manager) and refer it in the server.xml. In this way you don't need to worry about having the SSL certificate and the passphrase on the physical disk.

To install the cert to cert manager double click the certificate pfx file and follow the wizard steps. You can extract the pfx (refer https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html?jn554906de).

This feature is available on tomcat version 7.0.52 or above.

```
<Connector port="8443" 
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" 
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true"
           keyAlias="<common name of the cert>"
           keystoreFile=""
           keystoreType="Windows-My"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keepAliveTimeout="200000" />
```

Comment: What is the <alias of the cert> in case it resides in the Windows certificate store? Is it the thumbprint or the serial number or the name?

Comment: Its the common name of the certificate.

Comment: I though so as well, but it still doesn't work (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603375/tomcat-to-use-windows-certificate-store-for-ssl). Do I need an add-on for Tomcat to handle the Win cert store?

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm not using this feature anymore and it worked on 7.0.52 where I contributed the patch to tomcat.

Comment: I use Tomcat 9.0.10. It's odd that this doesn't work any more.

Comment: @Daniel is not working still?