# Configuring Tomcat to use Windows Certificate Store for SSL

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, ssl

I've deployed a number of SSL configurations, including both Tomcat (cacerts + keytool) and IIS (Windows Certificate Store + netsh http sslcert) so I'm familiar with these procedures.

Has anyone come up with a way to point Tomcat's SSL connector to a Windows Store (i.e. configuration, extension, plugin, etc.)? Just looking to centralize management of SSL deployments to one store, vs. having multiple stores.

Answer (score 3):

According to the answer on "[SSL enabling in Tomcat Windows server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335526/ssl-enabling-in-tomcat-windows-server)" you can specify keystore type as "Windows-My" in configuration of connector in server.xml, it worked for me on Tomcat 8.0.22 as well

```
<Connector port="8443" 
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" 
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true"
           keyAlias="<alias of the cert>"
           keystoreFile=""
           keystoreType="Windows-My"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keepAliveTimeout="200000" />
```

Comment: What do you put in the keyAlias in this case? I cannot start the SSL connector.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Connector port="8443" 
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" 
               scheme="https" 
               secure="true"
               keyAlias="<alias of the cert>"
               keystoreFile=""
               keystorePass=""
               keystoreType="Windows-My"
               clientAuth="false" 
               sslProtocol="TLS"
               keepAliveTimeout="200000" />
```

**keystoreFile** and **keystorePass** has to be set to empty string. [see my comment at bz.apache.org "BUG 56021"](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56021#c4)

If not set they will default to values that causes trouble.

**keyAlias** should  be either the friendly name (if it has one) or the common name of the certificate.

Comment: Martin's solution worked for me. It wasn't until I added keystorePass that it started working for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems not possible. From tomcat 8 documentation https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

> tomcat currently operates only on JKS, PKCS11 or PKCS12 format keystores.

Windows Store would require an specific connector similar to the 'WINDOWS-MY' of JSSE.

There is no reference in documentation to any plugin or connector to Windows Certificate Store.

Answer (score 0):

While Dmitry's solution works on Tomcat 8.0, from Tomcat 8.5 onward there is a small caveat: you need to explicitly set JSSE as [`SSLImplementation`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLImplementation.html). Hence the configuration becomes (considering also the new structure introduced in Tomcat 8.5):

```xml
<Connector port="8443"
           sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreType="Windows-MY"
                     certificateKeystoreFile=""
                     certificateKeyAlias="tomcat" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Alternatively, one can also set `useOpenSSL="false"` on the `AprLifecycleListener`.