# SSL Windows Certification Error on Tomcat 9

Tags: java, windows, ssl, tomcat

SSL is enabled in my server Tomcat 7.0.108. I enabled it according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883483

My Connector in serverx.xml is  :

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
           maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keyAlias="tomcat"
           keystoreFile=""
           keystorePass=""
           keystoreType="Windows-My">
</Connector>
```

But, in Tomcat 9.0.45 same configuration has an error.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init Error initializing SSL context
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Base64$Encoder.encode(Base64.java:261)
        at java.util.Base64$Encoder.encodeToString(Base64.java:315)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.addCertificate(OpenSSLContext.java:405)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init(OpenSSLContext.java:250)
```

Is anyone enable SSL with Tomcat 9 using Windows Certs?

Comment: Don't use the OpenSSL impl if you want to use Windows-MY. Use SunJSSE or OpenJSSE and your private key store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the [`SSLImplementation`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLImplementation.html) selected by Tomcat: the `OpenSSLImplementation` requires direct access to the private key, which is impossible if you use the `Windows-MY` keystore.

You just need to switch to `JSSEImplementation`, which results in the following configuration:

```xml
<Connector port="8443"
           sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreType="Windows-MY"
                     certificateKeystoreFile=""
                     certificateKeyAlias="tomcat" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

The default value of `sslImplementationName` automatically switches from `JSSEImplementation` to `OpenSSLImplementation`, whenever the Tomcat Native library is present (which is common on Windows): cf. [Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Connector_-_NIO_and_NIO2).

Remark that since Tomcat 8.5 the SSL configuration syntax changed. The one you use in your question has been deprecated in Tomcat 8.5 and removed from Tomcat 10.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works like you say. I just wonder can I use local computer certificates instead of user certificates?

Comment: According to this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65294041/4129188 , we can not. Thank you