# How to configure nginx/openresty to trust windows certificate store

Tags: windows, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, openresty

Similar to [SSL enabling in Tomcat Windows server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335526/ssl-enabling-in-tomcat-windows-server) question, how do I configure NGINX/OpenResty to use/trust Windows certificate store (especially the authorities)?

One option is to use some kind of NGINX plugin based on [NSS (Network Security Services)](https://hg.mozilla.org/projects/nss). I've actually found a repository for it [here](https://github.com/ttaubert/nginx-nss/tree/master), but no sure I can use it.

Are there any other solutions?